# Mousewheel Scroll HTML5 Video jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I want to be able to control my video using the mousewheel. So far I have managed that. I'm heading down the route of the mac pro website. I have bound it to the mousewheel and it starts to play when the user scrolls down.

What I want to do, is stop the video when a specific interval is reached, say 2 seconds. However, due to the length of frames, the video may skip past this, i.e. go from 1.98 to 2.05s...

To remedy this, I have used the Math.floor function. However, with this comes another problem - this will occur several times.

Does anyone have any ideas on either a better solution, like a threshold function?

```
        // Do stuff when specific time intervals are reached
        $(video).on('timeupdate', function() {

            if (Math.floor(video.currentTime) == 2){
                video.pause();
                console.log("Pausing video... ");
            }
            else if(video.ended){
                // Move to next section
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: why not something like `video.currentTime <= 2`

Comment: that would more likely be `video.currentTime >= 2`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use `>=` comparison instead of checking floored time?

```
            if (video.currentTime >= 2){
                video.pause();
                console.log("Pausing video... ");
            }
            else if(video.ended){
                // Move to next section
                return true;
            }
```